# Run command from NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, google-closure-compiler

I have an HTML5 project in NetBeans using Google Closure Compiler.
Is it possible to run the compile command directly from NetBeans?

I tried to use a macro, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can open terminal window in NetBeans using Window->IDE tools->Terminal and call the compiler from this terminal window